# Clustering only column in binary matrix with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, cluster-computing, distance

I would need some help in order to cluster my `binary values` in my matrix.
It's a binary matrix, here's an example:

```
G1  G2  G3  G4  G5  G6  G7  G8  G9  G10 G11 G12
Sp1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Sp2 1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Sp3 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1
SP4 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1
SP5 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0
SP6 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0
SP7 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
SP8 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
SP9 0   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0
```

And I would like to cluster `the columns` and not the rows.

The idea is to get the best possible representation of groups of points that are similar. 
Here in this example it should look something like this:

```
    G8  G1  G3  G5  G9  G2  G4  G11 G10 G12
Sp1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Sp2 0   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   0
Sp3 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1
SP4 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1
SP5 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
SP6 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0
SP7 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
SP8 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
SP9 0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0
```

I know that some methods exists but they ask to already have an idea of the number of cluster desired but I do not have nay idea of the number of cluster I will have.

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: I'm not sure what the second matrix represents... It looks like the same as the first matrix with just a few elements in different places. If you want a cluster of the columns, I would expect a vecter, the length of your columns, with a cluster index.

Comment: It was just to illustrate what the output should look like (so that same patterns in columns are clustered together)

Answer (score 0):

This is a little different approach. But maybe it will help get things rolling. I propose using a distance calculation. Here is my test data:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

m = np.random.randint(0,2,size=(10,10))
print(m)
```

```
[[1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0]
 [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1]
 [1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0]]
```

Using `scipy.spatial.distance` calculate the distance between all columns.

```
d = squareform(pdist(m.T, 'hamming'))
print(d)
```

```
[[0.  0.7 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.7 0.5 0.5 0.7 0.6]
 [0.7 0.  0.6 0.6 0.8 0.6 0.8 0.6 0.2 0.3]
 [0.5 0.6 0.  0.2 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.6 0.7]
 [0.5 0.6 0.2 0.  0.4 0.6 0.4 0.2 0.8 0.7]
 [0.5 0.8 0.4 0.4 0.  0.4 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.9]
 [0.7 0.6 0.4 0.6 0.4 0.  0.2 0.4 0.4 0.5]
 [0.5 0.8 0.4 0.4 0.2 0.2 0.  0.4 0.6 0.7]
 [0.5 0.6 0.4 0.2 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.  0.8 0.7]
 [0.7 0.2 0.6 0.8 0.6 0.4 0.6 0.8 0.  0.3]
 [0.6 0.3 0.7 0.7 0.9 0.5 0.7 0.7 0.3 0. ]]
```

Now you can sort based on distance to a column.

```
print(m[:,np.argsort(d[:,0])])
```

```
[[1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1]]
```

You can use this to sort by distance from any column i.e. the 4th column by changing `d[:,0]` to `d[:,4]` in the above block.